# Use unsigned kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, hibernate

I would like to enable hibernate whilst using Secure Boot on Ubuntu 20.04 which means self signing my own kernel images.

When Ubuntu automatically updates the kernel, it uses the signed image from the repository so the vmlinuz file is also signed. Is there a way to tell it to use the unsigned image or to remove the signature from the vmlinuz file?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

pesign -i vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic -o vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-unsigned -r -u 0

This will remove the signature from any kernel. This can be verified with:

sbverify --list vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-unsigned